Is this MOSFET compatible with this coreless motor?
As a warning, I will state at the beginning that this project is a hand-me-down and I do not have the complete specifications of components. This is a part of the problem.
I am working on building a mini-quadcopter. For the motor control, I am using the following components:

ESP8266
SI2302 N-channel SMD MOSFET
8520 coreless motors
IN5819 Schottky Diode
10K resistor

That is all the data I have on specifications. I don't even have a proper datasheet for the MOSFET or the motors.
The circuit is fairly standard:



Since I have no official data sheet, I found this and this, which seem to be close enough to my MOSFET. I know that at 100% duty cycle, the output is 3.3V from an ESP8266. The corresponding drain current for 3.3V GS-voltage in both datasheets exceeds 10A. I am pretty sure that the coreless motor should not be able to survive that. However when I tried it out for short periods of time, the motor seemed to work fine. I tried to measure the current using a DMM, but the motor slowed down drastically, and I gave up fearing incorrect reading.
So my questions are:

Is my interpretation correct?
Should I proceed with the current components since they seem to be working fine?
What changes would you suggest to be made without changing the MOSFET? Perhaps a voltage divider?
What MOSFET would your recommend in place of the SI2302?


Without the complete specifications it would be guessing in the dark. Could you provide pictures of the Mosfet, Motor and Diode or do they have markings on them? Also what voltage as VCC are you using?

@HansmitmFlammenwerfer I am afraid I don't have any more details. The MOSFET packet had "SI2302 Mosfet – N Channel – 2.2A – SOT-23" written, same as in the linked website. The 8520 motor are quite generic with no markings. I tried my best to collect every scrap of detail I could. This is all I have. For testing I used a single 3.7V 500mAh LiPo battery.

"Perhaps a voltage divider?" - where? What issue would that address?

@Finbarr I was thinking before giving input to the MOSFET so as to keep the V_GS low. I was just throwing it out.

@AlphaDelta to identify the MOSFET, are there any markings written on the MOSFET itself? They may be hard to read...
